# Pipe curl output after using a multi-line request payload

Tags: bash, curl, pipe

I have a curl request that accepts JSON as its payload. The JSON payload is a multi-line string. I'm having trouble piping the output of this curl after the `EOF`.

```
curl https://foo.bar/v1/baz \
        -H "FOO-BAR: BAZ" \
        -X POST -d @- <<'EOF'
{
    "foo" : "foo_foo",
    "bar": {}
}
EOF
```

This works, but if I want to pipe the output of this to something, for example `python -m json.tool`, I have a problem. The following doesn't work:

```
curl https://foo.bar/v1/baz \
        -H "FOO-BAR: BAZ" \
        -X POST -d @- <<'EOF'
{
    "foo" : "foo_foo",
    "bar": {}
}
EOF | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The here document doesn't begin until the next (logical) line after the command itself. Like any other redirection operator, `<<'EOF'` does not need to be the final token on the command line.

```
curl https://foo.bar/v1/baz \
    -H "FOO-BAR: BAZ" \
    -X POST -d @- <<'EOF'  | python -m json.tool
{
    "foo" : "foo_foo",
    "bar": {}
}
EOF
```